# Laravel cache when using memcached not returning same data when accessing in controller vs model

Tags: php, laravel, caching, memcached

I have created a utility class that I use to fetch data from an api and store in the cache by using the method `Cache::put()`. The code for storing data in the cache is shown below.

```
protected static function cacheData(array $data)
{
    foreach ($data as $id => $value)
    {
        Cache::put('ADWORDS_DATA_' . $id, $value, 60 * 6);
    }
}
```

This data can be retrieved using `Cache::get()` in tinker. But when I try to retrieve the data from cache in a controller method like this one,

```
$campaigns = Auth::user()->campaigns()->with(['adwords', 'facebookAds'])->get();

$data = [];
foreach ($campaigns as $campaign)
{
      $data[] = Cache::get('ADWORDS_DATA_' . $campaign->adwords->account_number);
}
```

the query returns null. I have already changed my app environment to staging from local to keep the cache from resetting on each request, but I can not figure out why the data I am storing in the cache is available through model methods and tinker, but not through the controller.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I just tried this out for you using multiple different driver types. I've tried it with `file`, `array`, `redis` and `memcached`. The only one I could reproduce this with was `array`. The rest of them seemed to work correctly. Maybe it has something to do with permissions, or who's executable ownership.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I am just a little bit dumb. I had forgotten that the cache is not persisted into the testing environment, so when accessing a route through a test I was not getting the results from cache I was expecting.